# Why am I getting a Migration Exception Error?

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool, magento-community, magento1.9.2.3

I am trying to use the data migration tool to move from 1.9.3.2 to 2.1.6. When I run this command

```
php magento migrate:settings /files/magento2/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.3.2/config.xml
```

I get a

```
Migration\Exception     
Invalid config filesname: /files/magento2/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.3.2/config.xml
```

The filepath to that file straight from Filezilla is

/files/magento2/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.3.2/config.xml

I can see config.xml in that location, I just can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you see in Filezilla is relative to your home directory, so in the shell you have to prefix it with `~`, which expands to the home directory. Otherwise the path is relative to the root directory `/`, which is obviously wrong.

```
php magento migrate:settings ~/files/magento2/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.3.2/config.xml
```

(assuming that you run it with the same user)

Comment: That was it! You have no idea how much I appreciate that!